# Using a key around multiple classes

Tags: php

Basically, I want to use a key and be able to call a function in a class from another class.

Maybe the example I will provide will give a better explanation as to what I mean. I thought of `const` but I would not be able to modify it from there.

I thought about parsing the key as a constructor, I was just wondering if there is any other better way of doing it since it'll be used in multiple classes.

**Class1.php**

```
<?PHP

class Class1 {
    public $key;

    public function setKey($k)
    {
        $this->key = $k;
    }

    public static function getKey()
    {
        return $this->key; // this won't work because static
    }
}


?>
```

**Class2.php**

```
<?PHP

class Class2 {
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo Class1::GetKey(); // Need to retrieve the key here
    }
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?PHP

require_once("Class1.php");
require_once("Class2.php");

$c1 = new Class1();
$c1->setKey("thekey");


$c2 = new Class2();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a static property, this way you can use it outside of the class and it can be changed later. For example:

```
class Class1
{
    static $key = 'ABC';
}

class Class2
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Original key: ' . Class1::$key . '<br />';

        Class1::$key = '123';

        echo 'New key: ' . Class1::$key;
    }
}

new Class2();
```

Prints:

```
Original key: ABC
New key: 123
```

But to keep the encapsulation concept, i suggest you to try to use `get` and `set` methods.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by turning the class storing common data into a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Essentially you just add a way to consistently return the same instance of the class:

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @var MyClass
     */
    protected static $instance;

    protected $key;

    public static getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new MyClass();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function setKey($k)
    {
        $this->key = $k;
    }

    public static function getKey()
    {
        return $this->key;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
// Both of these use the same instance of MyClass
MyClass::getInstance()->setKey('hello');
MyClass::getInstance()->getKey();
```

This allows you to write the class using instance properties and methods, without making everything static.

Further reading:

- [Design Patterns - PHP the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)
- [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Answer (score 0):

Make your class2 like this

```
<?PHP

class Class2 {
 public function __construct(Class1 $a1)
 {
    echo $a1->GetKey(); // Need to retrieve the key here
 }
}
?>
```

and make index.php like this ways

```
<?PHP

require_once("Class1.php");
require_once("Class2.php");

$c1 = new Class1();
$c1->setKey("thekey");


$c2 = new Class2($c1);
```

?>